# Show whole Text on Button Press

Tags: javascript, html

The text "Lorem ipsum..." is typed when the Submit button is pressed. The Show Text button should display the text in its entirety, but it currently clears the text beforehand.

I believe the Lorem ipsum part should be placed in its own

element, and I need help with that, please.

https://jsfiddle.net/cy4063tL/2/

```
HTML:
<div id="output" class="output-box">
    <div id="input-text"></div>
    <div id="typing-text"></div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="command-input" class="input-box" placeholder="Type your command...">

<div id="command-history"></div>

<button id="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>

<button id="showTextButton" onclick="showFullText()">Sofort anzeigen</button>

JavaScript:
function addToTypedOutput(text) {
    const typingText = document.getElementById("typing-text");
    const newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    newParagraph.textContent = text;
    newParagraph.classList.add("command");
    typingText.appendChild(newParagraph);
    typingText.scrollTop = typingText.scrollHeight;
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const inputElement = document.getElementById("command-input");
    const command = inputElement.value.toLowerCase();

    addToTypedOutput(`> ${command}`);

    if (command.startsWith("y")) {
        typeScript("yes", 1);
        const direction = command.substring(3);
        go(direction);
    } else {
        typeScript("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque", 100);
    }

    inputElement.value = "";
});

let typingInProgress = false;
let charIndex = 0;
let textToType = "";

function typeScript(text, typingSpeed) {
    const typingText = document.getElementById("typing-text");

    typingText.classList.add("type");

    function typeText() {
        if (charIndex < textToType.length) {
            typingText.innerHTML += textToType.charAt(charIndex);
            charIndex++;
            setTimeout(typeText, typingSpeed);
        } else {
            typingText.innerHTML += '<br>';
            typingInProgress = false;
        }
    }

    typingInProgress = true;
    charIndex = 0;
    textToType = text;


    typeText();
}

function showFullText(text) {
    const typingText = document.getElementById("typing-text");
    const paragraphs = typingText.querySelectorAll("p");
    
    if (paragraphs.length > 0) {

        paragraphs[paragraphs.length - 1].textContent = text;
    } else {

        typingText.innerHTML += `<p>${text}</p>`;
    }

    typingText.scrollTop = typingText.scrollHeight;
}
```

I tried to adapt it so that the Lorem ipsum text is created in its own

element, but unfortunately, it didn't work.